# For which $t\geq 0 $ is the sequence bounded

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

> For the power series $f(z)=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty} a_nz^n$ we introduce the set
>   $T_f=\{t\geq 0\mid|a_n|t^n\text{ is a bounded sequence}\}$. Let
>   $g(z)=\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^\infty}\frac{3^n}{n}z^{2n}$. What is $T_g$?

My approach:

I'd say that  $T_g=\left\{t\geq 0\mid\left|\frac{3^n}{n}\right|t^{2n}\text{ is a bounded sequence}\right\}=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3},\frac{1}{\sqrt 3})$, since  $\left|\frac{3^n}{n}\right|t^{2n}=\frac{3^n}{n}t^{2n}=\frac{1}{n}(3t^2)^n$, and the fact the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=0}^\infty} z^n$ converges for $|z|<1$

Now I'm a little in doubt, is this true, and if so, does my argumentation hold, or do I need to formalize it even more (if so, how could I formalize it even more)?

Comment: It's incomplete. (1). What happens when $3t^2=1$?.... (2) What happens when $3t^2>1$?

Comment: Also, for the case $3t^2 < 1$, you need to cite the fact that the series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$ converges for $|z| < 1$, and that if a series converges, then the sequence of its terms converges to zero and is therefore bounded.